How can I make sure that the TypeScript compiler will raise an error when calling an object (I'm using 'noLib')
The following TypeScript code compiles without errors.

Why is this the case; I'm calling an object, not a function?
How can I make sure that the compiler raises an error?

tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noLib": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./auto.dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "include": [
      "./src"
    ]
}

src/index.ts
type X = {
    'a': number
}

const x: X = {
    a: 5
}

x()

src/globals.ts
interface Array<T> {
    [n: number]: T
}
interface Boolean { }
interface CallableFunction { }
interface Function { }
interface IArguments { }
interface NewableFunction { }
interface Number { }
interface Object { }
interface RegExp { }
interface String { }


